# How can I display details(useState object) at the bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My React Code:[Image contains console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuZAL.png)

In the **first fetch** - I am providing email & password to login.
In the **second fetch** - It is fetching data with email id which was used in the first fetch.

I need to display the result which I have highlighted in the console. Like Student id,fname,lname,email,password at the bottom of same login page. Also I want to pass the details to display on another page.

```js
import './Login.css'
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc"
import { FaGithub, FaFacebook } from "react-icons/fa"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
const Login = () =>{
    const showConsole =()=>{
        //onclick it will display on console
        console.log("I am google, facebook, github");
    }
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
    const [details, setDetails] = React.useState({});
    
    
    function Login(){
        let item = {password, email};
        console.log(item);
        
        

        fetch("http://localhost:8080/student/login",{
            method:'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(item),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":'application/json',
                "Accept":'application/json'
            }
        }).then((e)=>{
            
            if(e.status === 200){
                console.log("Success",e)
                window.alert("Student Logged in successfully");
                fetch(`http://localhost:8080/student/oneStudentEmail?email=${email}`,{
                    method:'GET',
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type":'application/json',
                        "Accept":'application/json'
                    }
                }).then((student)=>student.json())
                .then((result)=>{
                    // console.log(result);
                    setDetails(result);
                    

                })
                
            }else{
                console.log("Not found",e,item)
                window.alert("Not found",item);
            }
        })
        console.log(details);
    }
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className='main_login'>
                <div><button className="btn_google"   onClick={showConsole}><FcGoogle   /></button></div>
                <div><button className="btn_github"   onClick={showConsole}><FaGithub   /></button></div>
                <div><button className="btn_facebook" onClick={showConsole}><FaFacebook /></button></div>
                <div className="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                    <h3>Enter Details</h3>
                    {/* input boxes */}
                    <input type="text"     className="form-control" placeholder="Email"    value={email}    onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}}  /><br/>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} /><br/>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={Login} > Login </button><br/>
                    Already have an Account?<Link to="/sign-up">Sign Up</Link>
                </div> 
                {/* {Here I want to show details also let me know how can I pass this details to another page} */}
            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Please don't keep a function named "Login" inside your "Login" (component). Rename it to "login" at least. Only classes & components should have names starting with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to display the results you can do

```
> <span>{details.id}</span>
> <span>{details.fname}</span>
> <span>{details.lname}</span>
> <span>{details.email}</span>
```

inside span or div (however you like) and to send data to another page you have 2 ways :
You can use Redux toolkit : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/
=> then you can display the informations wherver you want
OR
use the react navigation with params
like :

```
> const handleSelect = (fname: string) => {
    navigate('/dashboard', {
      state: {
        fname: details.fname,
      }
    });
  };
```

and then you can get it in the other page withe :

```
> props.location.state.fname in the dashboard page
```

Let me know if you need more help or explication

Comment: Hello @Aimen, I need more help to pass data to another component. Where can I use the above code?

Comment: Hello, i wish i understand good your question
you need to pass it directly as props like <component user={details} /> and then in your component you access to it 
const {user} = props;
i wish this will help or you can share your code with me then i can help you more :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `result` is of type `{id:string, fname:string , lname: string, email: string, password: string}` . You can display data by this:

```js
<div class="row">
   <div>Student ID: {details.id}</div>
   <div>Student First Name: {details.fname}</div>
   <div>Student Last Name: {details.lname}</div>
   <div>Email: {details.email}</div>
   <div>Password: {details.password}</div>
</div>
```

To share data between pages you can [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook if it is a simple use case or you can also use third part libraries like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/)